# Including Static Libraries & Header Files in Visual Studio 2015 Cross Platform C++ Project

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with including header & library files to my Visual Studio Mobile C++ Project for Android.

The files which I am trying to add to my Project are located in the %android_ndk%\sources folder with an "Android.mk" file - which should compile.

In Eclipse Studio I have compiled via Android.mk file (content is listed below) in the project directory. But the Visual Studio Project does not have anything like this.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LS_CPP=$(subst $(1)/,,$(wildcard $(1)/*.cpp))
LOCAL_MODULE    := <appname>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call LS_CPP,$(LOCAL_PATH))
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue <mylib>

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,<mylib>)
```

How can I achieve a proper build of the libraries?

Thanks in advance